# Finding the Gradient from these functions.

Tags: calculus

Find all functions $f(x,y)$ with gradient F = $(2xy + x, x^2 + y) $

So what I did first was try to find the following equations that match the problem

$\frac{df}{dx}$ = $ (2y +1, 2x+y)$

$\frac{df}{dy}$ = $(2x+x,x^2+1)$

I did it this way because x and y are constants. From here I get lost to where to go after I take the derivatives any advice on how to proceed would be good.

Comment: Are you sure $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ belong to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you should do. We have the vector equation

$$\nabla f(x,y) = {\bf{F}}(x,y)$$

We want to find the scalar field $f(x,y)$ for the given vector field ${\bf{F}}(x,y)$. In your question

$${\bf{F}}(x,y) = \left( {2xy + x} \right){\bf{i}} + \left( {{x^2} + y} \right){\bf{j}}$$

From these two equations it follows that

$$\left\{ \matrix{
  {{\partial f} \over {\partial x}} = 2xy + x \hfill \cr 
  {{\partial f} \over {\partial y}} = {x^2} + y \hfill \cr}  \right.$$

Integrating the first one with respect to $x$ gives

$$f(x,y) = {x^2}y + {1 \over 2}{x^2} + g(y)$$

Putting this into the second one we have

$${{\partial f} \over {\partial y}} = {x^2} + g'(y) = {x^2} + y$$

and consequently

$$g'(y) = y$$

and hence

$$g(y) = {1 \over 2}{y^2} + C$$

Finally we get

$$f(x,y) = {x^2}y + {1 \over 2}{x^2} + {1 \over 2}{y^2} + C$$

Comment: Nice thorough explanation.

Comment: When did you take the integral to get +C?

Comment: when finding $g(y)$ from the equation $g'(y) = y$.

Comment: Sorry I have one last question what is the significance of $g(y)$? Is it just a part of the notation?

Comment: $g(y)$ is the “constant” of integration w/r $x$: since $g$ doesn’t depend on $x$, it doesn’t change $\partial f/\partial x$.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is equivalent to finding functions $f(x,y)$ such that the differential form $\omega=(2xy+x)\mathrm dx+(x^2+y)\mathrm dy=\operatorname df$. First, we check to see if this is possible:$$
\frac \partial{\partial y}(2xy+x)=2x=\frac \partial{\partial x}(x^2+y)
$$
Thus, $\omega$ is closed and defined everywhere, so it is the differential of some function.
We can find such a function by integrating $\omega$ along the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ and declaring that $f(0,0)=0$. Parametrizing this line segment as $\bar x=xt, \bar y=yt$ gives$$\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= \int_0^1[(2xyt^2+xt)x+(x^2t^2+yt)y]dt \\
&=\int_0^1[3x^2yt^2+(x^2+y^2)t]dt \\
&=x^2y+\frac12x^2+\frac12y^2.
\end{align}$$
Choosing a different point $P_a$ with $f(P_a)=0$ for the starting point of the line segment amounts to changing the constant of integration, so we have $$f(x,y)=x^2y+\frac12x^2+\frac12y^2+C.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You are doing it backwards.

You want to find any possible solutions $F$ to an equation system which goes like this $$\begin{align}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} =& 2xy+x \\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=& x^2+1\end{align}$$