# Determine if this vector field is a conservative force field?

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

> Does $A(x, \, y) = (3x^2 + 2y^2)i + (4xy + 6y^2)j$ represent a conservative force field? If so, determine the potential $\phi$ in $A = \text{grad} \ \phi. $

From what I understand, we need to find $\phi$ such that $A(x, \, y) = \nabla{\phi} $

$A_x = 3x^2 + 2y^2 = \partial \phi/\partial x \qquad A_y = 4xy + 6y^2 = \partial \phi /\partial y $

If I perform a partial integration of $A_x$ with respect to x

Comment: show that the curl of $A$ is zero

Comment: ok I did curl A and I found that its 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}A_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}A_y$, i.e. for the mixed second partial derivatives

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}A_x=4y;\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial x}A_y=4y$$

By inspection, find that

$$\phi(x,y)=x^3+2y^3+2xy^2+k$$

for the potential function. By itself this shows that $\mathbf{A}(x,y)$ is conservative.

Comment: how did you find $\phi(x, \, y) = x^3 + 2y^3 + 2xy^2 + k$. I know there is some partial integration involved but there seems to something im not grasping.

Comment: Integrate $A_x$ with respect to $x$ to get $x^3+2xy^2+g(y)$. Differentiate this with respect to $y$ and compare with $A_y$ to determine $g$. Alternatively, you can find $\phi$ in one step by computing $\int_0^1 xA_x(xt,yt)+yA_y(xt,yt)\;dt$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1462939/265466 for a brief explanation of this integral.

Comment: @WAS - the $3x^2$ term in $A_x$ does not contain $y$ and so the  integral w.r.t. $x$ gives the $x^3$ in $A(x,y)$. The $6y^2$ term in $A_y$ does not contain $x$ and so the integral w.r.t. $y$ gives the $2y^3$ in $A$. You are left with $A^\ast_x=2y^2$ and $A^\ast_y=4xy$ and these are seen to be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ (respectively) of $2xy^2$. For a more formal approach suitable for more complicated functions, use the approach outlined by **amd**.