# Understanding the logic behind finding the Parent Function given an Exact Differential

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, intuition

I know the procedure to find the parent function but I do not understand the logic behind this procedure.

---

Lets suppose we are greeted with an *exact differential*:
$$du=y\,dx+(x+2y)dy\tag{a}$$ and we wish to find the parent function $u=u(x,y)$.

For the case of a general differential $df$ $$df(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy\tag{b}$$

Using the form of $(\mathrm{b})$ in the specific case of $(a)$ we have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=y\tag{1}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=x+2y\tag{2}$$

---

Starting with equation $(1)$; I attempt via integration wrt $x$ to find the parent function $u$:

$$u(x,y)=\fbox{$\color{red}{\int\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx=xy+g(y)}$}$$

Where $g(y)$ is an unknown function of $y$.

Now it is at this point that I am already confused for $2$ reasons:

**1.** The LHS of the boxed equation is $$\int\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\color{blue}{dx}$$ But, shouldn't this really be $$\int\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\color{blue}{\partial x}$$ since we are integrating a partial derivative? Therefore, Is this *really* the '**partial integral**'?

I write this as I see no justification in integrating a partial derivative when the integration differential is not partial.

---

**2.** The RHS has $g(y)$ as an unknown function of $y$. But why is this? Why not have an unknown function of $x$; $h(x)$ or an unknown function of $x$ & $y$; $q(x,y)$?

*Or* lastly; since I know that only one of these $3$ possibilities can be correct why not write the RHS as $xy+g(y)+\text{constant}$

---

Proceeding anyway to equation $(2)$ and following the same *recipe* as before
I find that 
$$u(x,y)=\fbox{$\color{#180}{\int\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dy=xy+y^2+r(x)}$}$$
Where $r(x)$ is an unknown function of $x$.

Iff $u(x,y)$ is equal to both $\color{red}{xy+g(y)}$ *and* $\color{#180}{xy + y^2 + r(x)}$ we must match them up I guess and conclude that $g(y)=y^2$ and $r(x)=0$. Is this logic correct?

If so we can write the parent function as $$u(x,y)=xy + y^2$$ 
`The problem is` that the **correct answer** is $$\color{#F80}{u(x,y)=xy + y^2+C}$$ where $C$ is a constant. But where on earth did the constant $C$ come from? I just matched up the two equations for $u(x,y)$ and found that there is no extra constant $C$.

---

I know this is an awful lot of questions for one post, but if anyone is able to answer some or *any* of them it will be greatly appreciated.

---

Just in case you were wondering; I got the idea for this question from another users' question on this site which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610249/given-an-exact-differential-how-do-you-find-the-function-that-satisfies-the-dif) and I have also read this [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971225/given-an-exact-differential-df-yz-dxxz-dyxya-dz-why-must-we-integrat) from the same user, but I'm still confused, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the question about partial integrals - I would claim it doesn't really make sense to define a separate partial integral (analogous to partial derivatives) because the point of partial derivatives is to take a function of many variables and differentiate it with respect to just one of them. But the regular Riemann/Lebesgue integral can already take a function of multiple variables and integrate with respect to just one of them. The reason $$\int\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx$$ is well defined is because $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is just a function of $x$ and $y$ so we can integrate normally.

As for why we don't write $xy+g(y)+C$, its because the constant can already be included in $g(y)$. (It would, however, still be perfectly acceptable to write it like that, its just not necessary). This also tells you why you missed the extra $C$ term - because you didn't account for the fact that $g(y)$ or $r(x)$ could have a constant term - just like integration in one variable.

Comment: That's excellent, you have dispelled my confusion about those $3$ issues, many thanks!

Comment: No problem - you did a good job explaining your questions and what you've already tried!

Comment: Well, you can only 'integrate normally' once you realize that integration is implicitly meant to happen over paths of constant $y$.

Answer (score 2):

(aside: the OP uses $u$ for two different purposes; I will opt to use $u$ for the variable — if I wish to express the variable $u$ as a function of $x$ and $y$, I will introduce a new letter for that function rather than reuse $u$)

The notation $\partial u / \partial x$ demands special notation, because $\mathrm{d} u$ and $\mathrm{d} x$ (and even $\mathrm{d}u/\mathrm{d}x$, should the differentials be ratios of one another) are things that are meaningful in the same sorts of contexts that one uses the notation $\partial u/\partial x$, and one needs notation to distinguish between them.

(this notation for partial derivatives has other deficiencies, but that's another issue)

However, in the partial integral, there is no ambiguity there — in fact, $\mathrm{d}x$ is *specifically desired*, since it correctly expresses the differential form to be integrated.

The thing that is different here is the $\int$. Integration here should happen over a *path*; paths of constant $y$ are implicitly intended here.

(and the scalar $\partial u/\partial x$, when restricted to a path of constant $y$, is equal to $\mathrm{d} u/\mathrm{d} x$, which is well-defined on paths of constant $y$)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that to me. Integrating over a path for which one of the variables does not change is a good way of interpreting the integral with the partial derivative as the integrand. Regards.